# 50:27 error Expected to return a value in "filteredTodos" computed property vue/return-in-computed-property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

проблема в том что выдает непонятную ошибку, не могу понять какое "Value" необходимо. Прикладываю скрин ошибки и кода. Извините за глупый вопрос, только начинаю программировать. Спасибо огромное!

[image: Ошибка которую показывает редактор.]

[image: Скрин][image: Скрин][image: скрин]

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Todo application</h2>
    <router-link to="/">Home111</router-link>
    <hr>
    <AddTodo @add-todo="addTodo"/>
<label>
      <select v-model="filter">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="completed">Completed</option>
        <option value="not-completed">Not-completed</option>
      </select>
</label>
    <hr>
    <Loader v-if="loading"/>
    <TodoList v-else-if="filteredTodos.length"
              v-bind:todos="filteredTodos"
              v-bind:key="filteredTodos.id"
              @remove-todo="removeTodo"
    />
    <p v-else> NOTODOS</p>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
import TodoList from '@/components/TodoList';
import AddTodo from "@/components/AddTodo";
import Loader from "@/components/loader";


export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      todos:[],
      loading:true,
      filter:"all"
   } },

    mounted() {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?_limit=9 ')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.todos = json
              this.loading = false
            }, 5000)
          })
    } ,
  computed: {filteredTodos() {
      if (this.filter === "all") {
        return this.todos
      }
      if (this.filter === "completed") {
        return this.todos.filter(t => t.completed)}
      if (this.filter === "not-completed") {
        return this.todos.filter(t => !t.completed)

      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeTodo(id) {
      this.todos = this.todos.filter(t => t.id !== id)
    },


    addTodo(todo) {
      this.todos.push(todo)

    }},
    components: {
      TodoList, AddTodo, Loader
    }}





</script>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте необходимый код в виде текста, а не картинки.

Comment: Здравствуйте, понял, прошу прощения. Исправил)

Answer (score 0):

computed: {
filteredTodos() {

```
  var filter
  
  if (this.filter === 'all') {
     filter = this.todos
  }

  if (this.filter === 'completed') {
    filter = this.todos.filter(t => t.completed)
  }

  if (this.filter === 'not-completed') {
    filter = this.todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
  }

  return filter
}
```

},